# countable set and disjoint subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ disjoint subsets of an infinite set $\Omega$. If $\Omega$ is countable then there can only be at most one infinite disjoint subset in $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$. However if $\Omega$ is uncountable then there can be more than one infinite disjoint subset in $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$.

Is this statement always true?

If true, this is it also true for $A_1,A_2,...$ infinite number of disjoint subsets?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:functional-analysis]?

Comment: $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,...\}, A_1=\{1,3,5...\}, A_2=\{2,4,6,...\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Is there countable infinite set with $n$ disjoint sets are infinite?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, this is the subject we are studying now.

Comment: But your question has nothing to do with Functional Analysis.

Comment: Lecture notes say either all disjoint subsets are finite or at least one is infinite but not all infinite.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, tag removed.

Comment: Consider $\{p,p^{2},p^{3},...\}$ where $p$ ranges over all prime numbers.